Elasticsearch field mapped to "text" even though it was mapped as "keyword"
I'm running Elasticsearch version 8.8.0, and I want to map source.as.organization.name and destination.as.organization.name as keyword fields. This is data sent to ES using Filebeat, that is automatically getting IP geoloc enriched.
The relevant portion of my index mapping is as follows.
"source": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "as": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "number": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "organization": {
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    ...
"destination": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "as": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "number": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "organization": {
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
...

When I check the "Index Templates" page on Kibana, the mapping for both fields are displayed as Keyword. However, when I looked at the records, both fields are still displayed with the t icon next to it, indicating they are text fields.
Why are the fields still stored as text fields, and how can I store them as keyword fields instead?

Once the index created you can't update a field type. You can create a new index to see your index template is working fine or not.
After creating the index if the mapping looks correct you can use the new index.
If you are using datastream index or rollover index, you can use _rollover API call to create a new index. After rollover check the latest datastream index mapping to make sure everything is fine. If all good, reindex the old data to the latest index.
After rollover or creating a new index that match the index_pattern in index template, if the new index mapping is still not match with the index pattern in index template, there can be multiple templates that override each other. To see which index template an index use during creation you can use the simulate API call.
POST /_index_template/_simulate_index/my-index-000001

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-simulate-index.html

I wasn't able to get the output of the simulate call - I only get { } as the output. And the mapping of the field was incorrect even after the index rollover. In fact, I checked the index's mappings under "Index Management" -> Indices -> current index -> Mappings, and I see the mapping that I had specified, i.e. keyword.

If you get empty body when you trigger simulate API call, you are using legacy templates.
Check templates with GET _template and grep your index pattern and grep by * to find which template matches.
Elasticsearch logs will mention about which legacy templates used during index creation. Check the logs and see find the template.
The order in the template. Increase to a higher number like 9999 and recreate the index.
check the following article for more info.
https://www.elastic.co/search-labs/blog/elasticsearch-index-template

I ran GET _template, and it only returned templates matching the .monitoring-XXXX and elasticlogs* index patterns. There are a lot more composable index templates that I have created and used, or have already been generated, e.g. ilm-history, logs, metrics, synthetics-XXXX that were not shown. I also only have one legacy index template elasticlogs-index-template, as shown in the "Index Templates" page on Kibana.

When I got the mapping of the current index via GET <index_name>/_mapping, I can see the exact configuration I set in the index template, i.e. keyword for the field. BTW, there is now a multi-field icon displayed on the Discover page for the 2 as.organization.name fields for each document now. It wasn't there yesterday, and I don't think my configuration was making this field a multi-field?

Nice, remove the old index and refresh the data view in kibana.

I can't remove the old index as I still need the data. Anyway, when I looked at Index Management -> Data Views, I see both fields with the "Type" displayed as text, keyword. When I clicked the pencil icon, I see the greyed-out "Type" dropdown box as 'text'. Is this why the field is still showing up as text?

it's probably because of the index pattern match multiple indices. One of the index indexed the same field as text and the other index indexed the same field as keyword. check like this GET <index_pattern*>/_mapping/field/as.organization.name.
If you can only see text field types, refresh the kibana view. About old index, use reindex and migrate the data from the old index into new one.

Yes, the index pattern is matching multiple indices. From the command you gave, I can see that the more recent indices are mapping the fields to keyword, while the older indices are mapping the fields to text. My question is why the newest documents are showing the fields as text, according to the t icon shown next to the field name. Shouldn't they be shown as k? Or will this only happen when all the fields in all the indices are mapped as text? That is unlikely to happen, as there is a huge amount of data.

Or will this only happen when all the fields in all the indices are mapped as text?
Exactly yes. This is why I ask for removing the old index. As a workaround, you can create another dataview index_pattern that match only the indices with the field type of keyword.

This is a data stream, so it seems like I can't choose the specific indices that were created after the change was made (I only see the name of the data stream in the "sources" list when creating a new data view). So at this moment, is the field mapped as text or keyword? I can't even see it under the Available fields pane in Discover, though I can still query for the field. But I can create a Lens with the fields now, so I guess they are mapped as keyword?

If you can create a graph with Kibana Lens it's most likely saved as keyword. It won't cause any conflict but you can't see the old data that saved as text. So I believe you're good now if you don't need to old data.

You're welcome Rayne. :)
